# Login screen in debian 5.0.3

Tags: debian, login

I'm a very fresh Linux user. It's my first step and I finished Debian 5.0.3 installation and I can't login. I type the username and password but nothing! Just the prompt changes to "debian@user$". I need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably at the console. 
You have either not installed Xorg or xorg is crashing. If it's the first case and you want to install Gnome, try: `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install gnome` . It will install every necessary dependency and you will be probably greeted with a graphical login screen upon completion of the installation.

Comment: Do what Kagig says or... You could try to type startx and see what happens. I bet you get some errors. Post the errors and we may can get you into a gui. btw you are logged into the console. Welcome to Debian. ;)

Comment: better would be aptitude update && aptitude install gnome-desktop-environment

Answer (score 2):

That sounds to me like you're logged in. You should be able to type commands at the prompt. What are you expecting that you're not seeing?